# Finding local minimum areas in the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a gray scale image with multiple local areas. The pixel value of local areas may be different. How to find the local minimum areas in the image?

In the attached file ([Gray image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkZR2.png)), I have 4 local areas with different pixel values.

Thank you!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! [Also see How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (your current badges suggest you haven't) and definitely check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Now, as for more on-topic comments, the tags you've added to this post seem to suggest you want a solution in opencv. Have you looked at its many functions for doing shape recognition? Have you got any code that reads in the image for the moment? And, finally, does your solution need to use opencv? Scipy can do this also easily.

Comment: @zamuz: Thank you so much for your suggestion. Actually, I want to find the local minimum area (closet part of the object to the stereo camera) in the depth image, then threshold and count the number of objects. That's it!

Comment: @Oliver: Thanks for your idea. I will try Scipy

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a connected component labeling, and then you keep the component with the lowest gray level.

If necessary (noisy images), you can start with a median filter, followed by a small opening and closing in order to clean you image.